# Parse metadata attributes of XML file in java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to parse XML file which is of the form.

```
<parent tag>
    <child tag>  
        <element key="property1">value</element> 
        <element key="property2">value</element>
    </child tag>
</parent tag>
```

How can I get the value of the `element` tag having `property1`? My code is as follows.

```
public static ArrayList<String> parseXML(URL url_str,URLConnection conn_str,String root_tag,String child_tag) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException 
{ 
    String s = null;
    ArrayList <String> List_value=new ArrayList<String>();       
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbF = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbF.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(conn_str.getInputStream());
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println("Root : "+doc.getDocumentElement());
    System.out.println("****************");
    NodeList nList= doc.getElementsByTagName(root_tag);
    System.out.println("****************");

    for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
         Node node = nList.item(i);
         if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
             Element element = (Element) node;
             NodeList nodelist1 = element.getElementsByTagName(child_tag);
             for (int i1 = 0; i1 < nodelist1.getLength(); i1++) 
             {
                 Element element1 = (Element) nodelist1.item(i1);
                 NodeList fstNm = element1.getChildNodes();
                 s=fstNm.item(0).getNodeValue();

                List_value.add(s);
            }
            for(int c=0;c<List_value.size();c++)
            {
                    System.out.println(List_value.get(c));
            }

        }

    }
    return List_value;
}
```

I am using DOM parser for the same. Kindly help.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the xml you are trying to parse.

Comment: XML file form is I am trying to parse XML file which is of the form.
<parent tag><child tag> 
<element key="property1">value</element> 
<element key="property2">value</element></child tag></parent tag>

How can I get the value of the element tag having property1?

I am using DOM parser for the same.
Kindly help.

Thank you.

Comment: Something wrong with the clipboard.It did not post the question as I typed.

Comment: Better format of XML
<parent tag>                                                      <child tag> 
<element key="property1">value</element> 
<element key="property2">value</element>                       </child tag>                                                        </parent tag>

Comment: @Soham: Show us what you've tried (i.e. post your code) for us to help you better. We would obviously help you out but don't expect us to write the code for you :)

Comment: Thanks!! Sujay...:) I have posted the code.

Comment: You should avoid whitespace in element-names ref: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This did the job here (DOM + XPath), more documentation here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html

Here is a good explanation about xpath and how it works: http://www.xmlplease.com/axis

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


public class XmlParseTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse("test.xml");

        XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//element[@key='property1']/text()");
        Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which jar file will I have to include in the classpath to implement XPath?

Comment: None, its a part of the standard Oracle/Sun JDK, remember to add the imports :)

Answer (score 1):

["An Introduction to APIs for XML Processing"](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/JavaTechandXML/#code14) would be a good point to start learning about XML parsing in Java

Comment: Code I wrote only returns the values of the child tag.But I have no idea about how to get the attributes of the tags.

Comment: @Soham: There's an [edit] (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11994277/edit) option to your question. Click on that (or on the "edit" link over here) and edit your own question. In the edit window post your code

Comment: @Soham: Edit your question, not my answer :)

Comment: What if XML file has multiple child tags with the same properties.How could we handle it in that case?Could you explain? Thanks...